# Is it possible to implement code clone detection in Azure Devops Build pipeline?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have configured a build pipeline (CI) in Azure DevOps. Following is the definition (yml) if that helps:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

We want to utilize Clone Code Detection ability of Visual Studio (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2012/06/28/visual-studio-2012-new-features-code-clone-analysis/) to find the duplicate code in the code base, so team can work on fixing the same.

What changes I would need to do to use this feature in the build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code clone detection can't be executed from the commandline. To implement what you want, you can, however, use the commandline code-clone detection tools from JetBrains Resharper CLI.

See: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/09/03/duplicate-finder-part-of-resharper-command-line-tools/

The problem with running these type of tools in the CI pipeline, is that there is no good way to report clones in the Azure DevOps UI or to make the build fail exactly when you'd want to. Some clones just are. Some of them are intentional. So ideally, the tools are ran in the IDE and developers solve the issues there.

With Jetbrains Duplicate Finder, you can at least mark sections of code as "excluded" in case duplication is intentional. With Code Clone Analysis you can add a solution specific config file to achieve this.